# Pull Data from Sql Table insert into Another using VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba

I am trying to insert an SQL column value from one table into another table using a subselect within an insert into sql statement using vba.  Can someone give me a hand with this?  Here is what I have:

```
SQL = "" & _
    "INSERT INTO dbo_CHEMICAL" & _
                "([NAME],[CAS#],[EU#])" & _
                "" & _
    "Values " & "('" & Me.CHEM_NAME_1.Value & "','" & Me.CAS_NUM_1.Value & "','" & Me.EU_NUM_1.Value & "');"

SQL2 = "" & _
    "INSERT INTO dbo_CHEMICAL_IN_COMPOUND" & _
                "([COMPOUND_ID],[CHEMICAL_ID],[PERCENT_BY_WEIGHT])" & _
                "" & _
    "Values " & "('" & Me.ICNUM.Value & "','" & 14 & "','" & Me.PERCENT_BY_WEIGHT_1.Value & "');"

DoCmd.RunSQL (SQL)
DoCmd.RunSQL (SQL2)
```

I plugged in a value of 14 in the bottom of the 2nd sql statement  and need it to be a select statement that will select the id (autonumber'd field) of the newly created record from the 1st sql statement.  Not sure how to do this.  Any hep is appreciated.

Comment: Please narrow down your question: it looks more like a functional spec and request for code writing service. Best regards,

Comment: My apologies, I'm trying to figure out if using an insert into sql statement with a subselect is the right way to grab the ID Value from record that is created with the 1st sql statement.  I'm basically needing to insert values from the form and get one value from a different sql table.  The code above works, I just don't know how to grab the ID value from the Chemical table and include it in my 2nd sql statement.  Does this help any?

Comment: Try to test these INSERT queries with some hardcoded values in SQL server Management Studio to ensure they work properly, they put it in VBA code with corresponding variables. Best regards,

Comment: I can get this to run but get the following error:  Run time error 3067 query input must contain at least one table or query. SQL2 = "" & _
        "INSERT INTO dbo_CHEMICAL_IN_COMPOUND" & _
                    "([COMPOUND_ID],[CHEMICAL_ID],[PERCENT_BY_WEIGHT])" & _
                    "" & _
        "Values " & "('" & Me.ICNUM.Value & "', (SELECT Max(dbo_CHEMICAL.ID) FROM (dbo_CHEMICAL)) ,'" & Me.PERCENT_BY_WEIGHT_1.Value & "');"

Comment: This is still a VBA code (btw, "" & _  seems uneccessary). Did you try INSERT query within SQL Server studio?

Comment: I suggest you: 1: Convert that VBA code into SQL code. 2: Post the actual error. I don't see any subselect in the code posted so far so your question doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather broad, so the answer is sort of generic. The correct syntax for SQL INSERT Query is as following:

```
INSERT INTO Table_Name (column1,column2,column3,...) VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

If, for example, `value1` is a string, then surround it with single quotation ''.
Even though this will work, but the recommended way is to create a parameterized query. Also, consider using `BulkInsert` for large data sets.

Hope this may help.

Comment: Thank for posting the syntax.  Basically what I'm need to do is use a sql select statement to grab value2 from a different sql table.  Can I do that?  Is that the correct way to do do this?  To use your example:  INSERT INTO Table_Name (column1,column2,column3,...) VALUES (value1,Select Max(tbl.id) from tbl,value3,...);  I hope this helps clarify what I am needing.  Thank you

Comment: It's a bit confusing: in order "to grab value2" you should use SELECT query, which is missing in your code. Instead, you posted two INSERT queries, and the answer was given pertinent to that topic. I recommend to accept this answer, and should you have additional questions, please post them separately. Thanks and regards,

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the confusion.  I'll have to think about rewording what I need.